# VBA, Using paths of files to copy and paste locally

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of 50 files path's in excel. How can I search for all these files in a network and copy them locally to a folder of mine?
What if the paths do not exist in the network, can I skip over these?
Thanks.

EDIT~~~

```
  Sub Copy_Certain_Files_In_Folder()
'This example copy all Excel files from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If the files in ToPath already exist it will overwrite
'existing files in this folder
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    FromPath = "I use network file here"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "local here"    '<< Change

    FileExt = "*.csv*"  '<< Change
    'You can use *.* for all files or *.doc for Word files

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

Comment: This has multiple answers on SO. My preferred method is using the scripting.filesystemobject's fileexist and other functions See if those keywords help you find what you're looking for.

Comment: @CodyG. thanks code-y!

Comment: For your reference http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Hi Harsha, i tried using this, didnt work for me, says file is not found(1st file). My question is: Do these work for network files aswell(not local).

Comment: Make sure topath and frompath are folders, not files. Make sure to change .CSV to your specific file extension like .xlsx ( yes it should work for network files)

Comment: @CodyG. so this one is for all files in a folder? Which one can you choose specific set of file(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file paths are in column A rows 1 to 50 on a sheet named mysheetname this should work.  Excuse my mistakes as this was typed on mobile.

```
Sub MyCopyFiles()
  Dim FSO
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim newpath as string: newpath ="C:\temp\"
  For i=1 to 50
    If  FSO.fileexists(Sheets("mysheetname").Cells(i,1)) then
      Call FSO.CopyFile(Sheets("mysheetname ").Cells(i,1),newpath+FSO.getFilename(Sheets("mysheetname").Cells(i,1)))
    End if
  Next i

End sub
```

Comment: Cody, where do I put the output folder to move the files too? Or would you just explain the inputs to this code?

Comment: Replace C:\temp\ with your desired path. Note it needs to end with a \

Comment: I get object required `Set FSO = CreateObject(Scripting.FileSystemObject)`  Also changed the sheet of my files to "mysheetname"

Comment: Try Call FSO.filecopy. also your paths--- shouldn't have quotations when they're in the cells, e.g. \\server\fileshare\myfile.txt NOT "\\server\fileshare\myfile.txt"

Comment: Sorry i'm replying to quickly. I tried the new code you updated to. And get object required on the `Set FSO = CreateObject(Scripting.FileSystemObject)`

Comment: Oh whoops. Need quotes around the Scripting.filesystemobject